# How to start a de-elevated cmd from admin command prompt

Tags: command-line, administrator, batch-file

I have an administrator command prompt.  I'd like to load another command prompt from here without administrator priveledges.

I'm pretty sure its some usage of 'runas' but I can't find the combination

Thanks!

edit: if possible, I would like to avoid entering in a password.

Comment: "RunAs" a non-admin user?

Comment: just run cmd from the run box?

Comment: The goal of my project is to be run as a 'setup environment' that will be on multiple users machines, as part of a batch process.  The 'cmd from run' won't do that for me (the cmd is just the first step), I did find the solution that required the account password, but ideally I wouldn't need it if possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a clean solution that doesn't rely on entering a user's password, you can create a task scheduler entry, then trigger it from the command line.  Assuming Win 7:

1. Open Task Scheduler: Control Panel | Administrative Tools | Task Scheduler
2. Create a new task by clicking on 'Create Task'
3. Give it a simple name, say 'RunCMD'. Ensure it is set to run as the user you want:
   [image]
4. Don't give it a trigger.  Add an action to run the program you want, `cmd.exe`:
   [image]
5. From the command line, activate the task using `schtasks.exe /run /tn RunCmd`

Comment: THis is a good potential solution.  This is part of a batch file thats going to be run many machines, and it will be tedious if I need to set this up for everyone.

Comment: You can set up a task on a remote machine also using the `schtasks` tool; if you run `schtasks /Create /?` you'll get a help description. Microsoft page on it [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766266.aspx). This would work if you can provide a run-as user/password which is part of your domain, so that you don't need to know the credentials of the local user in each case.

Comment: If you do decide to administer the tasks remotely, take note of [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/241825/schtasks-cant-administer-remote-tasks) too.

Answer (score -1):

From "runas" help:
`UserName should be in form USER@DOMAIN or DOMAIN\USER`
Do not use colon : as separator

Comment: I wonder if I could combine this with the username enviornment variables, but it would still require a password.